# Subquery returns more than 1 rows

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a beginner of coding trying to figure out how query works.

Right now I'm trying to select a specific column of several different rows from mysql and display them at the same row on C#, somehow I got error saying

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

After hours of thinking, still can't figure out the solution. Wish I could get help here.

Here's my code below:

```
Select Distinct T, DAY, TIME 
from climate
Where DAY in (
  Select Distinct DAY
  where DAY = '2020-01-22'
    and DISTRICT in
    (
      Select Distinct DISTRICT
      Where DISTRICT = '" + cmbArea.Text + "'
        and CITY in
        (
          Select Distinct CITY
          Where CITY = '" + cmbCity.Text + "'
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: If you are learning SQL, you should learn how to use parameters.

Comment: I'd think you'd need a `FROM` in every sub-SQL for it to give any rows.

Comment: As to multiple rows to one row: You may be looking for string aggregation. Please show some sample rows and the related result you are after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is weird. Let's look at the innermost expression:

```
[WHERE] city IN (SELECT DISTINCT city WHERE city = '...')
```

In the subquery you are not selecting from any table, so you are merely refering to the city from its parent query. The `WHERE` clause looks at one row at a time. So there is one row with one city. You compare this city with some variable and if it is a match you select this city. If not, then not. Then you use `DISTINCT` on the one or zero values as if there could be duplicates to remove. And then you're using `IN` which works with duplicates and without, so we would not force the DBMS to make rows distinct anyway. This complex expression is nothing else than

```
[WHERE] city = '...'
```

The whole query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT t, day, time 
FROM climate 
WHERE day = DATE '2020-01-22' 
AND district = @district
AND city = @city;
```

Even `DISTINCT` may be unnecessary here, but I can't know for sure. It depends on the table's unique key.

In C# you'd use something along the lines of:

```
MySqlCommand mySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT ...", conn);
mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@district", district));
mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@city", city));
MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(mySqlCommand);
```

I don't see, though, how any of your pseudo subqueries could return more than just one value.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm seeing a few issues here.

First of all, you've got no FROM in any of your subqueries. For example, this:

```
SELECT Distinct T, DAY, TIME
FROM climate
WHERE DAY IN (SELECT DISTINCT DAY
              WHERE DAY = '2020-01-22'
                AND DISTRICT IN (SELECT DISTINCT DISTRICT
                                 WHERE DISTRICT = '" + cmbArea.Text + "'
                                   AND CITY IN (SELECT DISTINCT CITY
                                                WHERE CITY = '" + cmbCity.Text + "')))
```

Should be:

```
SELECT Distinct T, DAY, TIME
FROM climate
WHERE DAY IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT DAY
    FROM Table
    WHERE DAY = '2020-01-22'
      AND DISTRICT IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT DISTRICT
            FROM Table
            WHERE DISTRICT = '" + cmbArea.Text + "'
              AND CITY IN (
                        SELECT DISTINCT CITY
                        FROM Table
                        WHERE CITY = '" + cmbCity.Text + "')))
```

Other than that, Like Juan said, you might as well go with GROUP BY because with your current code, I feel like it's going to select the first entry of each date in order based on your PRIMARY KEY while what you actually want (if I understood correctly) is all the entries where for example, the day is the 22nd of January.

So you could do something like this:

```
SELECT Distinct T, DAY, TIME

FROM climate

WHERE DAY = '2020-01-22'
AND DISTRICT = '" + cmbArea.Text + "'
AND CITY = '" + cmbCity.Text + "'

GROUP BY DAY, DISTRICT, CITY
```

If you do that, it should group by DAY, DISTRICT and CITY all at once. Therefore, if on any given day you've got a city in a specific district more than once, they'll be merged. Even then, if you're going to use city, I don't see the use for district unless there are multiple cities in different districts with the same name.

Otherwise, let's say you have San Fransico, California and Miami, Florida. If you have Miami, then the state is going to be Florida regardless because it's dependant on the city. You don't have to use it.